# Can we create managed package using eclipse and upload into different org's?

Tags: managed-package, eclipse, package, deployment

I was thinking if we could create managed packages using eclipse instead of Developer Edition and deploy the package into different Org's.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

No. A managed package has a source org, which must be a Developer Edition org. Eclipse, and other metadata tools, can install managed packages, or you can deploy the managed package as an unmanaged package in any org (assuming you have full access to the managed package org), but you can't make another org also have the same namespace. In other words, there can only be one source org for a managed package.